# Are there any c demos with netfilter?

Tags: c, linux, netfilter

I want to forward packets by netfilter, so I want to get some c demos to get start, thanks

Comment: please clarify you question --  does the build in netfilter not enough that you are going to write some it C? What functionality is missing from the buildin one?

Comment: I want to call the netfilter functions to do some work in my c program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the [netfilter](http://www.netfilter.org/) site? The documentation seems a bit dated, but there's a "Linux netfilter Hacking HOWTO" there.

Then play with the [source](http://lxr.linux.no/linux/net/netfilter/) :)